# Is VS Code capable of running code written in Jython?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing auto tests code in Jython, and decided to try using VS Code for it.
But I cannot set up Jython as an interpreter there.
After I putted my Jython file with ".py" extension into VS Code, application immediately suggested to "Select Python Interpreter" and warned that "Python is not installed (Please download and install Python)".

Can I set Jython as an interpreter manually somewhere and run code?

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4762) gave me some clue about my question, but I wanted to know what community currently thinks about it.

Comment: The issue you found says that it's not going to happen.

Comment: @harrymc you're right, looks like I hadn't read all comments attentively there.  Oh well, getting back to Atom then. Thanks.